# Any two normal coordinate charts $(x^i)$ and $(\widetilde{x}^j)$ are related by $\widetilde{x}^j=A_i^j x^i$ for some orthogonal matrix

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Here is a proposition excerpted from Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*.

[image]

I'm trying to show equation (5.19) holds for some orthogonal matrix $(A_i^j)$. According to Lee's proof, we have known $\widetilde{\varphi}$ restricts to $(\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B)\circ\varphi$ on some appropriate subset of $U$:
$$\widetilde{\varphi}=(\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B)\circ\varphi.$$
What's next? I thought it helpful to take out the $j$-th components of both sides:
$$r_j\circ\widetilde{\varphi}=r_j\circ[(\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B)\circ\varphi].\tag{$*$}$$
Here $r_j$ is to take out the $j$-th entry of an $n$-tuple. Except that $\widetilde{x}^j=r_j\circ\widetilde{\varphi}$, equation ($*$) seems to do no good to me in deriving (5.19). What am I supposed to do, please?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to make use of the fact that $\tilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ is a constant matrix!

Comment: @topolosaurus Thank you, but $\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ is not a matrix. Technically, $\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ determines a left-multiplication transformation $L_A:x\mapsto Ax$ if we denote the matrix representation of $\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $A$. I'm not sure if $L_A$ would make a difference in deriving (5.19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me denote $T=\tilde{B}^{-1} \circ B: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. From the proof you have that $T$ is a linear transformation. Actually is much more than that, it is a linear isometry, but anyway.

You want to prove the identity $\tilde{x}^i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} x^j$, for some **constant** coefficients $A_{ij}$. Here, $x^j$ is the j-th coordinate function of the chart map $\varphi$, and $\tilde{x}^i$ is the i-th coordinate function of $\tilde{\varphi}$.

From $\tilde{\varphi} = T \circ \varphi$, apply it to **any** point $p\in U$, the common intersection of both charts. Take the j-th component in both sides. This means

$$
\tilde{x}^i(p) = T^i(\phi(p))
$$
where $T^i$ is the i-th component of the above defined map. Since **you know that it is linear** there exist a matrix representation with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $\exists A_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\tilde{x}^i(p) = \sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij} (\varphi(p))^j = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} x^j(p)
$$
and since this holds for every $p\in U$ you have that **as functions**
$$
\tilde{x}^i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} x^j.
$$

Comment: I'm very sorry for a late reply, and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

This answer serves only as a complement to the answer of @topolosaurus, who came up with the key step.

People like me may wonder why those $A_{ij}$'s exist. Let me explain it. As I said previously in a comment, $\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ determines a left-multiplication transformation $L_A:x\mapsto Ax$ if we let $A$ denote the matrix representation of $\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B$ in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, evaluated at each $p$ in a suitable subset of $U$, the equation
$$r_j\circ\widetilde{\varphi}=r_j\circ[(\widetilde{B}^{-1}\circ B)\circ\varphi]$$
becomes
$$\widetilde{x}^j(p)=r_j\circ(A\varphi(p)),\tag{$**$}$$
where we interpret $\varphi(p)$ as a column vector. If we let $A_i^k$ denote the $(k,i)$-entry of $A$, ($**$) will take the form
$$\widetilde{x}^j(p)=r_j(A_i^1 x^i(p),\ldots,A_i^n x^i(p))$$
after we carry out matrix multiplication. Note that we have employed the summation convention. Now (5.19) follows immediately after we tell $r_j$ to do the job.